Given this icon: `<span class="material-symbols-outlined"> check_circle </span>` ,on hover, how do i make only the inside of the icon green?
i'm trying to make the background color of the icon green without it going over the circular shape of the icon
i've been trying to match the html element's border to the icon's shape, but the element's border is always slightly bigger, even with no padding

Please show us an example - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example We need the relevant HTML and CSS and reference to material icons.

Here's an example. It seems like 80% of the icon radius is enough for most cases. You can play with the percent if you want. It's best to check on different browsers.


var container = document.querySelector(".container")
for (var i = 10; i < 150; i++) {
  var span = document.createElement("span")
  span.style.fontSize = i + "px"
  span.classList.add("material-symbols-outlined")
  span.innerHTML = "check_circle"
  container.append(span)
}
.material-symbols-outlined {
  position: relative;
  cursor: default;
}

.material-symbols-outlined:hover::before {
  background: lightgreen;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  left: 10%;
  top: 10%;
  z-index: -1;
  content: '';
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined" />

<div class="container"></div>




Results can be achieved by simply adding ":hover" property to "material-symbols-outlined" & if you want to added uniquely to certain icons added unique class to them and add ":hover".
Try below code and feel free to modify, cheers.


.material-symbols-outlined {
  font-variation-settings:
  'FILL' 0,
  'wght' 400,
  'GRAD' 0,
  'opsz' 24
}


.material-symbols-outlined:hover {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border-radius: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />

<span class="material-symbols-outlined"> check_circle </span>




This method has exactly the problem that the question was asking be solved. The green goes slightly outside the circular black border of the icon. Try zooming in and it becomes obvious.

Sorry for misunderstanding from my side & I have fix for that too but I will recommend you to use other icon library like "iconify" which I found as best , you can get svg, css and more.
Talking about solution for this problem, follow this codepen link : https://codepen.io/Meet-the-reactor/full/rNggveQ
I still recommend iconify , must check once.
Thank You for response.
